# Openshift Origin - Router pod IP

Tags: openshift-origin

The router is unable to route the requests to any service in openshift origin ( v1.1.4) When troubleshooting I see

```
oc get pods --all-namespaces --selector=router --template='{{range .items}}HostIP: {{.status.hostIP}}   PodIP: {{.status.podIP}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}'
HostIP: 10.12.10.5  PodIP: 10.12.10.5
```

Maybe this is the problem since the router is not on the pod network and cannot route requests ?

Comment: When I am deploying ( forcing ) pods to the same node as router, the routes are working. It looks like this is an issue with openvswitch config.

Comment: THe output of your commands seems to be normal. Can you give some more information or error messages + DNS is up?

Comment: The PODs are somehow shoing as stale with "ip neigh"
10.1.2.2 dev tun0 lladdr 02:42:0a:01:02:02 STALE
10.1.2.3 dev tun0 lladdr 02:42:0a:01:02:03 STALE

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of types of routers. A HAProxy router is the most commonly used router. I'd imagine that is the kind you are using because you have it in a pod.

The router by itself will do very little. Again, I'm assuming you are using the Openshift web app and you are clicking on the link that is created. In order for this to resolve, you need to set up a Wildcard DNS ([check this Wildcard DNS article out](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/11/19/dns-your-openshift-v3-cluster/)). Once you have that set up and you have the router resolve to the correct node and given you have the router and routers configured correctly, the link should work.